# Using the custom element body for data

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am looking into implementing a custom datagrid but want the data to be provided inline as the contents of the custom element:

```
<x-datagrid>
  <row>
    <col>Value 1</col><col>Value 2</col>
  </row>
</x-datagrid>
```

You can clearly achieve this as the menu and tab elements populate based on this...how is this done though? I have looked at the component source for the core-dropdown-menu:

https://github.com/Polymer/core-dropdown-menu/blob/master/core-dropdown-menu.html

Doesn't tell me much...where else would I look?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with `Polymer.dom(this)` in the `ready` function.

An example, which loads data from child `<option>` elements into the component's `data` property:

```
ready: function() {
  var self = this; // Since "this" gets lost in the forEach
  Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('option').forEach(function(opt) {
    self.push('data', {id: opt.value, text: opt.textContent});
  });
},
```

Where my component looks something like:

```
<my-component>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</my-component>
```

Comment: Note that my component is intended to extend `<select>` and I'll be re-architecting it to wrap a proper `<select>` instead of using `<option>` elements directly, but it works as a proof of concept.